# How to set min and max value of a Kendo range slider after initialization

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, slider

I have two range sliders in a page to define a low range and high range values

when i select a low range the high range slider min value should start from low range slider max value. Any ideas how can i do that?
I've mentioned my code below

```
<div id="lowRangeSlider" class="rangeSlider" style="width: 500px; margin: 10px;">
<input type="hidden" />
<input type="hidden" />
</div>

<div id="highRangeSlider" class="rangeSlider" style="width: 500px; margin: 10px;">
<input type="hidden" />
<input type="hidden" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#lowRangeSlider").kendoRangeSlider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        smallStep: 1,
        largeStep: 5,
        tickPlacement: "both",
        change: function (e) {
            $("#lowMinValue").val(e.value[0]);
            $("#lowMaxValue").val(e.value[1]);
        }
    });
    var lowRangeSlider = $("#lowRangeSlider").data("kendoRangeSlider");

$("#highRangeSlider").kendoRangeSlider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        smallStep: 1,
        largeStep: 5,
        tickPlacement: "both",
        change: function (e) {
            $("#highMinValue").val(e.value[0]);
            $("#highMaxValue").val(e.value[1]);
        }
    });
    var highRangeSlider = $("#highRangeSlider").data("kendoRangeSlider");
```

Answer (score 0):

From Telerik's official forums:

> Currently there is no such functionality available. I would suggest to
>   submit your request in Kendo's UserVoice so other members of the
>   community can evaluate, comment on and vote for it.

However, there appears to be some workaround shown in the last post [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-can-i-change-a-property-of-the-slider-after-it-has-been-initialized)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to update the slider by doing it this way:

```
$("#slider").kendoRangeSlider({
    min: 10,
    max: 100
});

var slider = $("#slider").data("kendoRangeSlider");
slider.setOptions({
    min: 10,
    max: 500
});
slider.value([10, 500])
slider.resize();
```

The `slider.resize();` re-renders the slider again.